# How would a culture develop when there are 20 foot tall trolls that attack them?

Tags: culture, adaptability

In a world I'm building, there is a society of dwarves that live in a large, forested, snow-covered valley surrounded by mountains. The forests and mountains have large trolls that hunt the dwarves. The dwarves first colonized the valley 1300 years ago and I'm wondering how it would have influenced their culture. The dwarves came with the ability to craft tools and build houses. The trolls live underground and hunt goats and dwarves, and they turn to stone when exposed to sunlight. Troll tusks and fur are valuable. The trolls are about as intelligent as primitive humans, fiercely territorial, are up to 20 feet tall, and have thick skin and fur that is hard to pierce. I need to know how this would impact the dwarven culture while keeping the troll's numbers high.

Comment: Hi James. This is very vague. If you think about it - how did culture or a civilization develop with bears around? or tigers? or any other predator? This wouldn't be any different. Your citizens would develop weapons and fighting techniques against the trolls then either subdue them or eradicate them. No difference at all. Is there something specific that makes the trolls something other than just another predator? Are they intelligent? Magic?

Comment: Humans developed just fine on the territories of mammoths (with valuable tusks), cave bears, cave lions, wooly rhinoceroses and so on. Today humans are all over the place, and the mammoths, cave bears, cave lions and wooly rhinoceroses are in museums.

Comment: I see an answer has been accepted but assuming both trolls and dwarves are mammal-like, a 15 foot troll would reproduce very slowly, especially compared to a dwarve. They would be at risk of extinction if troll-dwarve altercations were common. The dwarves would probably have a huge advantage with numbers so it wouldn't disrupt cultural development much - but may inspire many myths.

Comment: Generally we don't like "how would this effect culture?" type questions, since they are too broad. In this case the answer is easy because the trolls have no huge effect on culture.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So I'm assuming that your "turn to stone" concept is the traditional Tolkienesque one, ie: Turned to stone = dead, not "turned to stone but revert to normal at night."  Which means you can't just go running around the hills hitting troll sculptures with sledgehammers.

This would make it harder, but my no means impossible, for your dwarves to go about their daily routine.  Barring something like a vast network of underground tunnels tracking a troll attack back its source would be easy.  Just estimate when the attack happened, how far at troll can go, and when the sun came up and you've got a search perimeter.  Then all you need do is collapse any troll-sized hole or cave you find! If you're really after troll-fur/tusks, smoke the sucker out and stick it full of arrows/crossbow bolts/spears, like they used to hunt bears back in the day.

If we're talking a network of tunnels in the hills, life gets harder.  Collapsing entrances only means a new hole gets used.  Your dwarves would probably go nocturnal (or have a nocturnal fighting force) and hunt the trolls through the cave system.  Pikes, fire, smoke, and determination would see the troll threat mitigated, and likely end with the trolls being completely or near-completely hunted to extinction in 1300 years.  After all, Humans have (probably) caused the extinction of larger predators (cave bears come to mind) and smart predators (wolves in most of western europe, lions outside africa).  Most importantly from your point of view, we've also caused the extinction of larger-than-us bipedal omnivores at about our intelligence level at least twice. (Neanderthals and Denesovians, with a "maybe" on several other large apes)

Comment: Stone sculptures of troll parts might not be as valuable as the parts themselves. The dwarves might need to go in after the trolls if they want the tusks and fur

Answer (score 8):

**It would develop just fine.**

Human culture developed in the context of predatory animals which attack and eat humans.  I am thinking of hyenas, lions, wolves, leopards, tigers etc.   Humans did fine and not so much the predators.

I here assume dwarves are more like humans than they are like goats.  Humans faced with a threat of this sort tend to team up and eliminate their predators.  Humans are very wily in this regard.  Traps work.  Poison works.  You can just hunt for the things.

Trolls have a disadvantage as compared to tigers because tigers can move day and night, and can hide.  If a troll attacks, you can draw a circle around the site of the attack with a size corresponding to time between attack and daylight.  Longer time = bigger circle.  When the sun comes up, the troll is somewhere in that circle as a stone.  I have to think it would not be that hard to track a 15 foot tall animal.  Find it and break it.

Or take the entire stone such that the troll wakes up at night bound and helpless.   Perhaps the troll can be persuaded to help find others of its kind?

Comment: I wonder if the trolls can be cooked? A pre-dawn banquet might be yummy.

Comment: Exactly. Those trolls are easier to kill than an elephant, and men have hunted elephants down near extinction for no good reason at all. With the aggressiveness of the trolls, the dwarfs would be extremely motivated to kill each and every troll they encounter.

Comment: I changed it so that it's just that they turn to stone when exposed to the sun- sorry about the misconception

Comment: @cmaster-reinstatemonica AFAIK elephants weren't hunted to near-extinction until humans with access to firearms appeared in their habitat. While pre-industrial humans might have hunted elephants occasionally, they never seriously endangered their survival.

Comment: However, pre-industrial humans [exterminated wolves in many parts of Europe, and eradicated them from Great Britain in the 17th century](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolf#Eurasia). But a wolf is not nearly as dangerous to a human as a 20 foot tall troll. The main motivation was to protect lifestock from wolf attacks.

Comment: @Philipp Right. Humans started hunting down elephants for fun and profit when it got easy and safe for a human to do so. Before that, killing an elephant has always been a dangerous endeavor, and due to an elephants generally non-hostile behavior, there was very little gain in killing an elephant that did not justify the danger of doing it. My point was that intelligent bipeds are the real monsters that will kill even tougher adversaries than a troll for even less gain.

Comment: @Philipp Mammoths, mastodons, and the last gomphotheres might want a word about that...

Comment: In regards to cooking troll meat, would dwarves need to consume the meat immediately since any part of the troll will still turn to stone, even when dead? Does that make storage of troll meat impossible or just difficult as it has to be covered at all times.

Answer (score 4):

#### Trolls will be hunted to extinction

You have valuable commodities (fur and tusks) which are stationary and defenseless during the day. It's like leaving $50 notes around in the wild. Humans will raid the defenseless troll camps during the day, and seize them for parts.

Very primitive man while getting their act together may temporarily become nocturnal (day is safe, night they need to respond), but humans only need one good day on the battlefield and they've got the upper hand from then on.

Comment: i changed the question to clear up the misconception so now it says they turn to stone in sunlight.

Answer (score 1):

**Live Underground**

The dwarves would build underground with entrances too small to allow the trolls to enter

At night time, they just go home and lock the door and there isn't anything the trolls can do.

During the day, they hunt the trolls by shining mirrors into the troll caves and at night, they leave traps to kill or wound the trolls.